# How do I make pip point to pip for python 3.7 instead of python 3.6?

Tags: python, pip

Everytime I try to update pip for version 3.7 of python it just does it for python 3.6.

python --version returns 3.7.3, but pip --version returns the version with (python 3.6) at the end in parentheses

Comment: @SmartManoj thanks but how? What do I type in commandline?

Comment: Make sure pip3.7 path appears first in environmental variable

Answer (score 2):

```
pip3.7 [command]
```

You could make an alias which you update whenever you want to update the version of pip you are using.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the specific answer you are looking for, but it should be worth noting that just using `pip` can get nasty on systems with multiple python environments installed (hence, your SO question here!)

I'd suggest that you consider targeting your python binary, and then use `pip` from there:

**`/path/to/python -m pip <pip commands here>`**

With this, you will never be confused about which `python` is getting packages installed to it. It's drawn out, and it's not fun to type all that, but with multiple python environments on a system, it can save a headache and avoid future confusion!